# How to reference the NsdManager

Tags: android

I want to discover services on a local area network using the network service discovery manager, as per the example in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd.html):

> mNsdManager.discoverServices(
>           SERVICE_TYPE, NsdManager.PROTOCOL_DNS_SD, mDiscoveryListener);

My problem is I don't know how to reference an isntance of the `mNsdManager`. I've tried

```
NsdManager mNsdManager = new NsdManager();
```

but apparently the `NsdManager` constructor is private. I've looked for a method that returns a singelton, but no luck there.

Any idea how to get a reference to the `NsdManager`?

Answer (score 1):

Ah, found it

```
mNsdManager = (NsdManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.NSD_SERVICE);
```